# Do companions level up before joining?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

As per the title, do companions level as you level prior to joining your party, or are they simply a set level regardless of when you join them to your party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each companion has a fixed level that they start at, and there is some variation between the different companions.  No matter what level you are when you recruit a companion, they will always be the same level.

You can find out what each one's starting level and stats are from [here](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Will accept when the minimum time has passed!